# carregar API do Google maps após o onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5, google-maps

Tenho um sistema que atualmente funciona com a api do google maps, mas percebi que o site fica aguardando essa API ser carregada para então terminar de carregar a pagina.

na pagina inicial(index.php) tenho a tag assim:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
...
.
.
.
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
.
.
.
</html>
```

Eu não uso o google maps no index.php, só é feito dessa maneira, porque depois que a página é carregada o usuário clica em um botão que faz um load para a carregar o mapa assim:

```
$("#conteudo").load('veiculoDescarga.php');
```

Quando essa tag *script* do google é colocada dentro desse arquivo veiculoDescarga.php a api não funciona não carrega as demais dependências dela.

```
// quando executo qualquer coisa da API tipo esse exemplo 
new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();   
//Tenho essa mensagem de erro
TypeError: google.maps.DirectionsRenderer is not a constructor

//outro exemplo
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

//outro erro exemplo
TypeError: google.maps.event is undefined
```

Alguém sabe se é possível fazer essa API funcionar após fazer o $.load() ou o onload ?

**Edit 01**
Para exemplificar melhor vou deixar as imagens abaixo com as explicações:

Na imagem abaixo a tag do *googleapis* é roda normalmente veja que esta única tag faz a chamada buscando as demais tags de dependencia e as inseri, este caso esta ok.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas eu não quero que ela seja carregada ai de inicio, eu quero que seja carregado essa tag do googleapis quando eu chamar o evento .load() do jQuery, mas veja que quando faço isso a tag é carregada mas não faz as chamada das demais dependencias
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Tenta assim:

```
$("#conteudo").load('veiculoDescarga.php', carregarMapa);

function carregarMapa(){
   // aqui você coloca os scripts de carregamento do mapa.
}
```

Comment: Não funcionou, deu o mesmo erro

Comment: tem um pagina html com javacript quando o usúario clica em um veiculo, ele pega as coordenadas do veiculo com javacript/jQuery e abre um $("<div>").dialog(), esse dialog abre um html onde esta o script com as configurações da API do goole e canvas do mapa

Comment: O Dialog abre um html com a tag canvas e os javascript necessarios(parametros) para abrir o mapa

Comment: Esse javascript necessário para abrir o mapa foi o que você colocou dentro de  function carregarMapa() { //aqui }  ??

Comment: Quais são as outras referencias que não carregam quando vc coloca o carregamento da api dentro do veiculos.php?

Comment: Editei a pergunta para tentar detalhar melhor o problema